# Post on review page identified as first-question

Tags: support, review

[First Questions tab on the Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions) displays the first questions a new user has ever asked. I came across a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965312/fastest-way-to-show-numbers-of-users-from-database) which is the 8th one displayed on OP's info page (who has been a member for more than a year) but still displayed for review. Attached the screen shot of `/review` page.

[image]

What could be the reason, question was edited, user merged accounts, or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've verified the behavior you pointed out with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7983677/709202), as well.

My guess is that the review page actually shows the first *few* questions (perhaps up to five?) asked by a new user, possibly even according to some criteria such as the total number of upvotes or views. Note that this is hinted at by the plural "questions" in the phrase "the first **questions** a new user has ever asked."